# org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to find deployed service

Tags: java, ignite

I have created Ignite service which implements both Service and a dummy Test interface. I am trying to invoke Test interface method through below code

```
IgniteServiceTestInterface cntrSvc = ignite.services()
    .serviceProxy("IgniteServiceTestInterface", IgniteServiceTestInterface.class, false);
System.out.println(cntrSvc.invokeNext(1));
```

method is already implemented in Service and returns next counter whenever gets invoked. But instead I am getting an error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to find deployed service: IgniteServiceTestInterface
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProxy$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(GridServiceProxy.java:167)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.invokeNext(Unknown Source)
at IgniteClient.main(IgniteClient.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am missing herestrong text

Comment: Was the service properly deployed? Can you show the code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone who would like to quickly deploy ignite service:

```
Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
String configFile = "ignite.xml";
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configFile);

// Deployment the service
IgniteServices services = ignite.services(ignite.cluster().forServers());
services.deployClusterSingleton("IgniteServiceTestInterface", new IgniteServiceTestImpl());

// Accessing the deployed service
IgniteServiceTestInterface cntrSvc = ignite.services()
    .serviceProxy("IgniteServiceTestInterface", IgniteServiceTestInterface.class, false);
System.out.println(cntrSvc.invokeNext(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

it is working fine, there was a Service name mismatch with the registered service. Once I corrected it, i was able to invoke the service name.

Comment: This should be in the comment not in the answer.